# forcing nginx to redirect to server root

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have the following line in nginx:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

As far as I understand, it rewrites all queries to files that are not found to `index.html`.
Meaning, that `index.html?foo=bar` and `idontexist.html?foo=bar` leave the same result which screws up Google crawling.

How can I not rewrite but redirect to the default url?

The perfect solution would be even without the `index.html`.
So `http://domain.com/idontexist.html?foo=bar` would redirect using 301 to `http://domain.com/?foo=bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've shortened VBart's code snippet above. It works as it should:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ / =301;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @to_home;
    ...
}

location @to_home {
    return 301 /$is_args$args;
}
```